# Sticky at top of lists node at certain time

Tags: nodes, cron

I would like to sticky node at certain time and update time of publishing. I tried with module [Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/scheduler) but it unpublishes content I need published content it is more like republishing and put that content at the top.

I tried some with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module but no success. Is it possible to that somehow?

Comment: rules should be able to do that, what did you try, how did it fail, under what circumstances do you want it change, etc - more information will make it easier to understand exactly what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [Rules Scheduler](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rules/tree/rules_scheduler) (part of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module) is what you're looking for. "[Publish content exactly 24 hours after it was created](https://www.drupal.org/node/517674)" contains step by step instructions about how to do so (using the Rules Scheduler).

Here are some video tutorials about a few variations of your question (some are pretty close to your question), which are all resolved with Rules Scheduler:

- [Schedule front page publishing](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/schedule-front-page-publishing).
- [Publish a newly created Drupal node on a future date](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-rules-scheduler-part-3).
- [Send a follow-up email one week after a user registers](http://www.webwash.net/tutorials/how-send-follow-emails-using-rules-scheduler-drupal-7).

Ps: There is also the [rules-scheduler](/questions/tagged/rules-scheduler) tag, specific to the Rules Scheduler.

Comment: Thank you, I will try... I never used Rules it will take time, I hope that I will solve my problem :)

Comment: Investing time to learn about Rules is for sure a good investement. It's 1 of the 4 modules that should proably be used in any sites, i.e. Views-Rules-Flag-Messages (VRFM for short). Amazing how far you can get in mostly any site with only using these 4 modules ...